# Ask for Google Maps Version in my app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app that uses Google Maps. Since, with the new Api in Android, the map wont work if the user don't have the Google Maps  app up to date, is there any way that my app can know the version that the user have installed? And... can my app know wich version  is the last in Google Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the map wont work if the user don't have the Google Maps app up to date, is there any way that my app can know the version that the user have installed?

Your app does not care about the version of Google Maps. Your app cares about having the Play Services Framework installed.

My sample apps, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Basic), use an `AbstractMapActivity` that wraps up the details of checking for the Play Services Framework, in a call to `readyToGo()`:

```
  protected boolean readyToGo() {
    int status=
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
      return(true);
    }
    else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
      ErrorDialogFragment.newInstance(status)
                         .show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                               TAG_ERROR_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
    }
    else {
      Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_maps, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      finish();
    }

    return(false);
  }
```

This will return `true` if `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` itself returns `true`. Otherwise, if possible, it will display a dialog (there's an `ErrorDialogFragment` inner class) that will lead the user to install the Play Services Framework. Or, it will display a `Toast` for an unrecoverable problem (though production code should use something else, like a crouton).

`GooglePlayServicesUtil` has its [own set of JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html).

Comment: Very nice and helpful answer! Thank you very much.